# APC Not Enabled in Apache

Tags: centos, php, alternative-php-cache

I know this questions has been beat to death, but I've read almost all the responses and it hasn't solved my issue. I installed APC (no noted errors), I told PHP.ini to enable it and I made sure I am running PHP in FastCGI with SuExec turned off.

Still I have no go.

> PHP / suEXEC Configuration

- Default PHP Version (.php files)     **5**
- PHP 5 Handler **fcgi**
- PHP 4 Handler **none**
- Apache suEXEC **off**
- Apache Ruid2 **off**

> php.ini Configuration

Alternative PHP Cache   apc.enabled
Alternative PHP Cache   apc.shm_segments
Alternative PHP Cache   apc.shm_size

When I run the APC.php file I get this message:

> No cache info available. APC does not appear to be running.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up finding the answer after much more searching.
The problem exists when the apc.so file does not exist in the module_dir specified in the PHP.ini file.

Long story short, you can either change the directory or just move the apc.so file from it's directory to the one specified in PHP.ini file.